# I need help to understand these assembly instructions

Tags: assembly

I found this asm instructions who push a parameter into the stack before a call, but i think there is some useless instructions.

```
mov eax,esi
neg eax
sbb eax,eax
lea ecx,[esp+10h]
and eax,ecx
push eax
```

Can i just replace theses instructions with the following:

```
lea ecx,[esp+10h]
push ecx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe what you have is equivalent. The `sbb` instruction may leave `eax` as zero (all 0 bits) or negative one (all 1 bits), which will definitely affect what happens to the value pulled from `ecx` in the `and` instruction.

It looks like the original code will push either `esp+10h` or `0`, depending on what was in `esi` to start with.

Comment: Just to make it clear: `esp+10h` will be pushed (ie. the address not the value from memory, due to the `LEA`) if `esi` is non-zero.

Comment: can i consider that the esi register is used by a previous function to store parameter to pass to the one above?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace those instruction with

```
lea  eax, [esp+10]
test esi, esi
cmovz eax, esi    ;; push zero (i.e. esi) iff esi==0
push eax
```

or

```
       test esi, esi
       jz   skip
       lea  esi, [esp+10]
skip:  push esi
```

Neg will subtract eax from 0 and that produces carry flag unless eax==0;
When carry flag is set, sbb a,a produces -1 (otherwise 0), that is used as a selection mask. It's not completely clear that cmov instruction will be faster than the branch.